# power query split long query into multiple queries - Any Benefits?

Tags: powerquery

I have a query which is (round numbers) 40 steps in length.  Most are Add/Transform Columns but there are about 8 merge queried embedded

There are multiple data feeds upfront (handled by other queries) which feed into this query (as the root source of data as well as for the merge queries).

The number of records we are talking from each is no more than 10,000.

The above main query takes forever to execute.

Am asking whether there is any benefit to splitting the above 40 step query into several (using the Extract Previous functionality).

Or in lieu of splitting the query, any ideas on how to speed things up would be most helpful.

Added chunks of code (non-sequential since wanted to show various line executions

```
let
Source = RMD_Input_File,
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 2, 1, Int64.Type),
#"SSN - Text" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "SSN - Text", each Number.ToText([SSN],"000-00-0000"),type text),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"SSN - Text",{"Index", "NameLast", "NameFirst", "NameMi", "SSN", "SSN - Text","PartDOB", "PartDOD", "AnnuityFlag", "Status1", "Status2", "YearsOfSvc", "SpouseSSN", "SpouseDOB", "SpouseDOD", "AcctType", "PartName", "Address1", "Address2", "City", "State", "ZIP", "DCBC Conversion Date", "Plan-1", "Ext-1", "Status-1", "HoldFlag-1", "HoldReason-1", "CurBal-1", "EOYBal-1", "TermDt-1", "Plan-2", "Ext-2", "Status-2", "HoldFlag-2", "HoldReason-2", "CurBal-2", "EOYBal-2", "TermDt-2", "Plan-3", "Ext-3", "Status-3", "HoldFlag-3", "HoldReason-3", "CurBal-3", "EOYBal-3", "TermDt-3", "Plan-4", "Ext-4", "Status-4", "HoldFlag-4", "HoldReason-4", "CurBal-4", "EOYBal-4", "TermDt-4", "Plan-5", "Ext-5", "Status-5", "HoldFlag-5", "HoldReason-5", "CurBal-5", "EOYBal-5", "TermDt-5", "Plan-6", "Ext-6", "Status-6", "HoldFlag-6", "HoldReason-6", "CurBal-6", "EOYBal-6", "TermDt-6", "Plan-7", "Ext-7", "Status-7", "HoldFlag-7", "HoldReason-7", "CurBal-7", "EOYBal-7", "TermDt-7", "Plan-8", "Ext-8", "Status-8", "HoldFlag-8", "HoldReason-8", "CurBal-8", "EOYBal-8", "TermDt-8", "Plan-9", "Ext-9", "Status-9", "HoldFlag-9", "HoldReason-9", "CurBal-9", "EOYBal-9", "TermDt-9", "Plan-10", "Ext-10", "Status-10", "HoldFlag-10", "HoldReason-10", "CurBal-10", "EOYBal-10", "TermDt-10", "Plan-11", "Ext-11", "Status-11", "HoldFlag-11", "HoldReason-11", "CurBal-11", "EOYBal-11", "TermDt-11", "RET_TERM_DATE", "NOTE"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Reordered Columns",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Status-1", "Status-2", "Status-3", "Status-4", "Status-5", "Status-6", "Status-7", "Status-8", "Status-9", "Status-10", "Status-11"}),

#"1 in Clergy Plan" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "1 in Clergy Plan", each ClergyPlan([#"Plan-1"])),
UpdateStatus1 = Table.ReplaceValue(#"1 in Clergy Plan", each [#"Status-1"], each if [#"Status-1"]>= 20 then [#"Status-1"] else if [1 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [PartDOB] < Vlookup("Start Initial", RMD_Dates, "Category", "Date") then 32 else [#"Status-1"], Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Status-1"}),
#"Active in Plan 1" = Table.AddColumn(UpdateStatus1, "Active in Plan 1", each ActiveInPlan([#"TermDt-1"], [#"Status-1"])),

#"2 in Clergy Plan" = Table.AddColumn(#"Active in Plan 1", "2 in Clergy Plan", each ClergyPlan([#"Plan-2"])),
UpdateStatus2 = Table.ReplaceValue(#"2 in Clergy Plan", each [#"Status-2"], each if [#"Status-2"]>= 20 then [#"Status-2"] else if [2 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [PartDOB] < Vlookup("Start Initial", RMD_Dates, "Category", "Date") then 32 else [#"Status-2"], Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Status-2"}),
#"Active in Plan 2" = Table.AddColumn(UpdateStatus2, "Active in Plan 2", each ActiveInPlan([#"TermDt-2"], [#"Status-2"])),


#"Max Term Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Active in Plan 11", "Max Term Date", each List.Max({[#"TermDt-1"],[#"TermDt-2"],[#"TermDt-3"],[#"TermDt-4"],[#"TermDt-5"],[#"TermDt-6"],[#"TermDt-7"],[#"TermDt-8"],[#"TermDt-9"],[#"TermDt-10"],[#"TermDt-11"]}),type date),

#"Min Term Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Max Term Date", "Min Term Date", each List.Min({[#"TermDt-1"],[#"TermDt-2"],[#"TermDt-3"],[#"TermDt-4"],[#"TermDt-5"],[#"TermDt-6"],[#"TermDt-7"],[#"TermDt-8"],[#"TermDt-9"],[#"TermDt-10"],[#"TermDt-11"]}),type date),

RBY = Table.AddColumn(#"Year Reach RMD Age", "RBY", each if [RET_TERM_DATE]=null and [Max Term Date]=null then "" else List.Max({Date.Year([RET_TERM_DATE]),[Year Reach RMD Age],Date.Year([Max Term Date])})),
Initial_or_Reocurring = Table.AddColumn(RBY, "Initial_or_Reocurring", each if [RBY]="" or [RBY]>RMD_Year then "No RMD Due"
else if [RBY]=RMD_Year then "Initial" else "Recurring"),

#"0 in Any Plan" = Table.AddColumn(Initial_or_Reocurring, "0 in Any Plan", each if List.Contains({[#"Status-1"],[#"Status-2"],[#"Status-3"],[#"Status-4"],[#"Status-5"],[#"Status-6"],[#"Status-7"],[#"Status-8"],[#"Status-9"],[#"Status-10"],[#"Status-11"]},0) then "Yes" else "No"),

#"Missing/Foreign Address" = Table.AddColumn(#"0 in Any Plan", "Missing/Foreign Address", each if [ZIP]= null then "Foreign" 
else if List.AnyTrue({[Address1]=null,[City]=null, [State]=null}) then "Missing" else null),

ClergyLay = Table.AddColumn(#"Missing/Foreign Address", "ClergyLay", each if List.NonNullCount(List.Distinct({[1 in Clergy Plan],[2 in Clergy Plan],[3 in Clergy Plan],[4 in Clergy Plan],[5 in Clergy Plan],[6 in Clergy Plan],[7 in Clergy Plan],[8 in Clergy Plan],[9 in Clergy Plan],[10 in Clergy Plan],[11 in Clergy Plan]}))=1 
then (if List.First(List.Distinct(List.RemoveNulls({[1 in Clergy Plan],[2 in Clergy Plan],[3 in Clergy Plan],[4 in Clergy Plan],[5 in Clergy Plan],[6 in Clergy Plan],[7 in Clergy Plan],[8 in Clergy Plan],[9 in Clergy Plan],[10 in Clergy Plan],[11 in Clergy Plan]}))) ="Yes" then "Clergy" else "Lay")
else "ClergyLay"),

Status = Table.AddColumn(ClergyLay, "Status", each if Vlookup([Status2], status2, "Status2", "Result") = "Deceased" then "Deceased"
else if Vlookup([Status2], status2, "Status2", "Result") = "Active" and [Status1]<>"LE" and [PartDOB]<Vlookup("Start Initial", RMD_Dates, "Category", "Date") and [ClergyLay]= "Clergy" then "Inactive - 72" else Vlookup([Status2], status2, "Status2", "Result")),

#"active in clergy plan or active clergy" = Table.AddColumn(Status, "active in clergy plan or active clergy", each if List.AnyTrue({
[1 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-1"]<19,
[2 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-2"]<19,
[3 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-3"]<19,
[4 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-4"]<19,
[5 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-5"]<19,
[6 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-6"]<19,
[7 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-7"]<19,
[8 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-8"]<19,
[9 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-9"]<19,
[10 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-10"]<19,
[11 in Clergy Plan]="Yes" and [#"Status-11"]<19,
[Status1]<>"LE" and [Status1]<>"" and [Status]="Active"
}) then "Yes" else "No"),

#"RMD YN-U" = Table.AddColumn(#"active in clergy plan or active clergy", "RMD YN-U", each if List.AnyTrue(
{Text.Start([#"Plan-1"],1)="U" and [#"Status-1"]>=20,
Text.Start([#"Plan-2"],1)="U" and [#"Status-2"]>=20,
Text.Start([#"Plan-3"],1)="U" and [#"Status-3"]>=20,
Text.Start([#"Plan-4"],1)="U" and [#"Status-4"]>=20,
Text.Start([#"Plan-5"],1)="U" and [#"Status-5"]>=20,
Text.Start([#"Plan-6"],1)="U" and [#"Status-6"]>=20,
Text.Start([#"Plan-7"],1)="U" and [#"Status-7"]>=20,
Text.Start([#"Plan-8"],1)="U" and [#"Status-8"]>=20,
Text.Start([#"Plan-9"],1)="U" and [#"Status-9"]>=20,
Text.Start([#"Plan-10"],1)="U" and [#"Status-10"]>=20,
Text.Start([#"Plan-11"],1)="U" and [#"Status-11"]>=20
}
)
then "RMD" else "No RMD"),

#"Status-U" = Table.AddColumn(#"RMD YN-U", "Status-U", each Text.Combine({
if Text.Start([#"Plan-1"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-1"]) else "",
if Text.Start([#"Plan-2"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-2"]) else "",
if Text.Start([#"Plan-3"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-3"]) else "",
if Text.Start([#"Plan-4"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-4"]) else "",
if Text.Start([#"Plan-5"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-5"]) else "",
if Text.Start([#"Plan-6"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-6"]) else "",
if Text.Start([#"Plan-7"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-7"]) else "",
if Text.Start([#"Plan-8"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-8"]) else "",
if Text.Start([#"Plan-9"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-9"]) else "",
if Text.Start([#"Plan-10"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-10"]) else "",
if Text.Start([#"Plan-11"],1)="U" then Number.ToText([#"Status-11"]) else ""
},",")),

#"adjCurBal-U" = Table.AddColumn(#"EOYBal-U", "adjCurBal-U", each if [active in clergy plan or active clergy] = "Yes" then
List.Sum(
{if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-1"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-1"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-1"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-1"],1)="U" and [#"Status-1"]>19 then [#"CurBal-1"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-2"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-2"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-2"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-2"],1)="U" and [#"Status-2"]>19 then [#"CurBal-2"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-3"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-3"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-3"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-3"],1)="U" and [#"Status-3"]>19 then [#"CurBal-3"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-4"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-4"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-4"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-4"],1)="U" and [#"Status-4"]>19 then [#"CurBal-4"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-5"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-5"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-5"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-5"],1)="U" and [#"Status-5"]>19 then [#"CurBal-5"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-6"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-6"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-6"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-6"],1)="U" and [#"Status-6"]>19 then [#"CurBal-6"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-7"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-7"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-7"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-7"],1)="U" and [#"Status-7"]>19 then [#"CurBal-7"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-8"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-8"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-8"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-8"],1)="U" and [#"Status-8"]>19 then [#"CurBal-8"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-9"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-9"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-9"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-9"],1)="U" and [#"Status-9"]>19 then [#"CurBal-9"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-10"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-10"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-10"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-10"],1)="U" and [#"Status-10"]>19 then [#"CurBal-10"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-11"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-11"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-11"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-11"],1)="U" and [#"Status-11"]>19 then [#"CurBal-11"] else 0}
)
else
List.Sum({if Text.Start([#"Plan-1"],1)="U" and [#"Status-1"]>19 then [#"CurBal-1"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-2"],1)="U" and [#"Status-2"]>19 then [#"CurBal-2"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-3"],1)="U" and [#"Status-3"]>19 then [#"CurBal-3"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-4"],1)="U" and [#"Status-4"]>19  then [#"CurBal-4"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-5"],1)="U" and [#"Status-5"]>19  then [#"CurBal-5"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-6"],1)="U" and [#"Status-6"]>19  then [#"CurBal-6"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-7"],1)="U" and [#"Status-7"]>19  then [#"CurBal-7"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-8"],1)="U" and [#"Status-8"]>19  then [#"CurBal-8"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-9"],1)="U" and [#"Status-9"]>19  then [#"CurBal-9"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-10"],1)="U" and [#"Status-10"]>19  then [#"CurBal-10"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-11"],1)="U" and [#"Status-11"]>19  then [#"CurBal-11"] else 0
})),
    #"adjEOYBal-U" = Table.AddColumn(#"adjCurBal-U", "adjEOYBal-U", each if [active in clergy plan or active clergy] = "Yes" then
List.Sum(
{if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-1"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-1"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-1"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-1"],1)="U" and [#"Status-1"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-1"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-2"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-2"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-2"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-2"],1)="U" and [#"Status-2"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-2"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-3"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-3"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-3"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-3"],1)="U" and [#"Status-3"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-3"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-4"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-4"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-4"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-4"],1)="U" and [#"Status-4"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-4"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-5"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-5"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-5"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-5"],1)="U" and [#"Status-5"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-5"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-6"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-6"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-6"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-6"],1)="U" and [#"Status-6"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-6"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-7"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-7"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-7"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-7"],1)="U" and [#"Status-7"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-7"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-8"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-8"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-8"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-8"],1)="U" and [#"Status-8"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-8"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-9"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-9"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-9"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-9"],1)="U" and [#"Status-9"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-9"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-10"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-10"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-10"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-10"],1)="U" and [#"Status-10"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-10"] else 0,
if List.AnyTrue({Text.Start([#"Plan-11"],2)="UM",Text.Start([#"Plan-11"],2)="UC",[#"Plan-11"]="U99999"}) then 0
else if Text.Start([#"Plan-11"],1)="U" and [#"Status-11"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-11"] else 0}
)
else
List.Sum({if Text.Start([#"Plan-1"],1)="U" and [#"Status-1"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-1"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-2"],1)="U" and [#"Status-2"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-2"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-3"],1)="U" and [#"Status-3"]>19 then [#"EOYBal-3"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-4"],1)="U" and [#"Status-4"]>19  then [#"EOYBal-4"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-5"],1)="U" and [#"Status-5"]>19  then [#"EOYBal-5"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-6"],1)="U" and [#"Status-6"]>19  then [#"EOYBal-6"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-7"],1)="U" and [#"Status-7"]>19  then [#"EOYBal-7"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-8"],1)="U" and [#"Status-8"]>19  then [#"EOYBal-8"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-9"],1)="U" and [#"Status-9"]>19  then [#"EOYBal-9"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-10"],1)="U" and [#"Status-10"]>19  then [#"EOYBal-10"] else 0,
if Text.Start([#"Plan-11"],1)="U" and [#"Status-11"]>19  then [#"EOYBal-11"] else 0
})),
```

Comment: Share a copy of the code. Are you buffering tables or lists when appropriate?

Comment: That’s a rather difficult question to answer. As a starter you may find some inspiration from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/best-practices … not all points listed there are for speed; and there are plenty other articles on the internet as well. May also want to consider the whole workflow and the data sources, pipeline or any constraints which other tools can be used, e.g. SQL

Comment: Added sample code.  Note I do use several functions as well throughout the code as well